# Replacing case with IIF in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, iif

```
SELECT 
    patientname, patientinsurance, patienthistory,
    (CASE 
        WHEN patientinsurance IS NOT NULL THEN 'insured'
        WHEN CDPrintBatchId IS NULL THEN 'uninsured'    
     END) AS insurancestatus
FROM 
    [dbo]..database
WHERE
    admissiontime BETWEEN '2020-09-03' AND '2020-09-04'
```

So for my above query, I want to use `IIF` instead of `CASE`, because I want to show only uninsured patients, would something be correct? Because if I only use one case in my case scenario, the null will should up in my insurancestatus column instead of uninsured.

```
SELECT 
    IIF(patient("Null") = 0, 'YES', 'NO');
```

Basically I just want the result for null showing up in result, excluding not null

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear.  Please update your question with examples of expected results and sample data.

Comment: Omg, I love IIF.  This is the best question of the day

Comment: The case statement compares two independent fields - but your IIF example is testing one condition.  It does not look like a directlogical replacement of what your CASE statement is doing.   The CASE statement has an order of precedence in it that you are not duplicating in your IIF statement.  Your CASE has no ELSE in it also.

Comment: `I want to iif instead of case` -> why?

Comment: Why using proprietary syntax (similar to Oracle's DECODE) when there's Standard SQL compliant CASE (which is way more powerfull), just for saving a few keystrokes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query is equivalent to the one posted except it returns 'uninsured' in all FALSE cases.  insurancestatus will not be NULL

```
SELECT patientname, patientinsurance, patienthistory,
        iif(patientinsurance is not null, 'insured', 'uninsured') insurancestatus 
FROM [dbo]..database
where admissiontime between '2020-09-03' and '2020-09-04';
```

Comment: Is there way to only for insured, that  means I don't want to care about uninsured status

Comment: Yes, if you added the WHERE clause: patientinsurance is not null

Comment: It wouldn't need the iif column then because it would only return the insured

Answer (score 0):

So you want to eliminate all records for 'uninsured?

Then why not hard coded uninsured for insurance status and use a where clause limit to remove the uninsured records.

```
SELECT patientname, patientinsurance, patienthistory, 
  CASE WHEN patientinsurance is null then 'uninsured' else 'insured' end as InsuranceStatus
FROM [dbo]..database
WHERE admissiontime between '2020-09-03' and '2020-09-04'
  AND
```

Comment: Hey sorry I meant I want case or if, but only want to add one case scenario, where something is null

Comment: Could you please edit what you mean into the original question. Even with this detail, it's not clear.